# How do I dereference a pointer to an object in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, class, object, pointers

I am a computer engineering student and as part of an assignment I had to create a database of objects. The instructions for the assignment suggested that I build the database using an array of pointers to the objects which I did using a dynamically allocated array

```
typedef employee* employeePtr;
    employeePtr* employees = new employeePtr[6];
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
        employees[i] = new employee();
    }
```

I then initialized the array by setting each member of the array equal to the address of each object

```
    employees[0] = &objO1;
    employees[1] = &objC1;
    employees[2] = &objC2;
    employees[3] = &objW1;
    employees[4] = &objW2;
    employees[5] = &objW3;
```

(I am not sure if this is relevant to the problem but the objects were of the same parent class but, of different child classes) I had to run the same functions for each of the objects so, I created a for loop to iterate through the array and preform the functions for each of the objects by dereferencing the pointer in the array

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
        *employees[i].getSalary;
        *employees[i].displayInfo;
    }
```

It did not work and I got the error *expression must have class type*. This was my first time using a dynamic array in C++ so my first thought was that since the array itself works using pointers I had to double dereference it

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
        **employees[i].getSalary;
        **employees[i].displayInfo;
    }
```

that did not work either and gave me the same error. So how do I properly dereference the pointers so that I can easily call all of the member functions using a for loop.

Comment: Your question should have a [mre]. Compile your code with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) and all warnings and debug info (so `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` ....). Then use the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger. Take time to **read the documentation of your compiler and of your debugger**

Answer (score 3):

The `.` operator for member access has higher [precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than the `*` operator for dereferencing.

You should add parenthesis to override the precedence:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
    (*employees[i]).getSalary;
    (*employees[i]).displayInfo;
}
```

Another way is using `->` operator. `A->B` means `(*A).B`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
    employees[i]->getSalary;
    employees[i]->displayInfo;
}
```